# R: Subset/extract rows of a data frame in steps of 12

Tags: r, subset

I have a data frame with data for each month of a 26 years period (1993 - 2019), which makes 312 rows in total.
Unfortunately, I had to lag the data, so each year goes now from July t to June t+1. So I can't just extract the year from the date.

Now, I want to exclude the 12-month data for each year in a separate data frame. My first Idea is to insert in the first column the year and use the lapply function to filter afterward.

For this, I created the following loop:

```
n <- 1
m <- 1993
for (a in 1:26) {
  for (i in n:(n+11)) {
    t.monthly.ret.lag[i,1] <- m
  }
  n <- n+1
  m <- m+1
}
```

Unfortunately, R isn't naming the year in steps of 12. Instead, it is counting directly in steps of 1.

Does anyone know how to solve this or maybe know a better way of doing it?

Comment: It is not fully clear to me what you are trying to achieve exactly, and what `t` is, but you can always index rows in steps of 12 using  `seq`, and you can use `seq` also on dates, such as `seq.Date(from = as.Date("1993-01-01"), by = "month", length.out = 312)` or `seq.Date(from = as.Date("1993-06-11"), by = "month", length.out = 312)`, ,etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
y.first <- 1993
y.last <- 2019

month.col <- rep(c(7:12, 1:6), y.last-y.first+1)
year.col <- rep(c(y.first:y.last), each=length(month.name))
df <- data.frame(year=year.col, month=month.col)
```

This yields a dataframe with months and year correspondingly tagged, which further allows to use `dplyr::group_by()` and so on.

Comment: Bots flagged your question for removal due to lack of context. Now we can't learn from it. Please update answer with an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a 312 element long vector giving the year (and one giving the month) using `rep()` and `seq()`. Then you can attach them as additional columns to your data.frame or just use them as reference for month and year.

```
month = rep(seq(1:12),27)
year = c(matrix(rep(seq(1:27),12),ncol=27,byrow=T)+1992)
month = month[7:(length(month)-6)]
year = year[7:(length(year)-6)]
```

The month vector counts from 1 to 12, beginning at 6, the year vector repeats the year 12 times (the first and last only 6 times).